# Remove an element of vector using for_each

Tags: c++

I have a class `Student`. It has a member `nameCoef` of type `int`.
Every `Student` object is stored in a vector, which is a member of `Group` class.
I need to remove an object from vector if `nameCoef == 1`.
Accessing of `nameCoef` is possible only by using member function `getNameCoef()` of class `Student`.

So, I tried this:

```
struct removeStudent
{
    void operator()(const Group &a)
    {
        group.erase();
    }
};

void processGroup()
{
    for_each(this->group.begin(), this->group.end(), removeStudent());
}
```

But I get an error:

> a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

How to solve it?

Comment: Use `std::remove_if` and then `vector.erase`.  Your method is inefficient, calling `erase` each time the nameCoef matches.

Comment: I need to use for_each as a task

Comment: *I need to use for_each as a task* --  FYI, `for_each` is the wrong tool for the job of erasing from a vector.  It is probably the worst tool to use.  To erase items from a vector that match a criteria is done using `remove_if`, then `vector.erase`.  Anything else -- you're being taught C++ badly.  You're also not supposed to mutate the container that you're calling `for_each` with.  Thus your "task" is wrong.

Comment: So, it's impossible or a bad practice?

Comment: For every `erase()`, you are invalidating the `end()` iterator.  So if you call `for_each`, and the second parameter denotes the `end()`, does `for_each` update itself to reflect that `end()` has changed when you erase an item?  That's the issue, and the reason why you shouldn't use `for_each` for this.  Also, what does you internal `erase()` function actually do?  It certainly is not the `vector::erase` method, as `vector::erase` requires iterators as arguments.